# Accessing boot menu on unbranded device

Tags: ubuntu, boot, android

So I've been given an android "laptop" to fix. I planned to install Ubuntu (as a dual-boot preferably- though Lubuntu would probably be better in this situation), because the experience it provides with Android falls short of actually useable. It doesn't connect to wifi, the touchpad is crappy (can't do much about that), the system is extremely slow, and the keyboard insists that it is Japanese and that there's a second set of arrow keys where there are letters and numbers that I need. And more. It's just bad, and I can't fix these things in Android.

One problem. I can't access the boot menu. Or the BIOS menu, for that matter.

There are no buttons on the sides of the device, there are no volume buttons on the keyboard (usually the solution for tablets), and mashing all of the function keys on boot has no effect.

How do I get to the boot menu?

Manual: https://pastebin.com/1DbJs5Pw (this is the only documentation included in the box)
Model number: Comax_f900a
Kernel Version: 3.10.37
Android Version: 5.1.1 (Lollipop)

Comment: I can find No support for that model, you will need plenty of luck figuring that one out.

Comment: Evidently it is made in India and is a cheap throw away device never intended to be worked on, just used as is.

Comment: Figures. It was bought for very cheap (under $100 iirc). Build quality seems to confirm that. It was bought as a cheap device for a kid who ended up unable to use it. (It won't connect to wifi, so... no apps and no YouTube.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably no bootloader or the ability to install an arbitrary OS. Its an arm system (and lacks the lovely painless standard platform that lets you run nearly any os that supports the architecture on a system that x86 has). Arm basically licences the processor architecture, each manufacturer and model has its quirks  - and your kernels and OSes are often built for that device or family of devices.

You would be looking for a way to flash on a third party *recovery* - essentially a bootloader. *Rom* - which is the OS build/distribution *specific* for that model.

If you had *serious* skills (which I lack personally!)- you could get an idea of what the specifications of the [laptop in question are here](http://specdevice.com/showspec.php?id=4a97-4968-ffff-ffff9268258d). [This suggests](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/combination-recovery-mode-t3572275) that ADB would let you get into the stock recovery mode. Beyond that, you're literally going to have to build a good chunk of your system from scratch. Fun hacker project, but at that price range, something like a pinebook would be less of a headache

Comment: I don't have access to the device anymore... Could have it brought here within the next year, but probably not worth it.

Comment: Probably not. I guess